# problem in pgRouting with data from google earth

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

Hello i am new in forum an in Postgesql,postgis and pgRouting.
I try to make a pgrouting for my city roads.

I use googlemaps to make a lines with coordinates of the roads and export the results in kml file.
example `<MultiGeometry><LineString><coordinates>22.950164627408352,40.592917358186945 22.950657309819846,40.592514769916995</coordinates></LineString></MultiGeometry>`

but i have problem with the insert in postgresql
The queries for table and make the geometry for roads.

```
 CREATE TABLE roads(
    "id" integer PRIMARY KEY,
        "Name" text NOT NULL,
    "Lenght (m)" numeric CHECK("Lenght (m)" > 0)
);

SELECT AddGeometryColumn('','roads','the_geom','4326','MULTILINESTRING',2);
```

After i use an insert like this but i have problem with MULTILINESTRING

```
    INSERT INTO roads VALUES(1,'Kwnn/nou Kanarh',1000,ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromKML('<MultiGeometry><LineString><coordinates> 
26.683023,37.7939654,0.0 26.6839457,37.7941011,0.0 26.6857266,37.7944063,0.0 26.687851,37.7948472,0.0 26.69034,37.7955084,0.0 26.6947603,37.7972888,0.0 26.6975284,37.7980687,0.0 26.6992879,37.7984926,0.0 26.701498,37.7993573,0.0 26.7026782,37.79989990000001,0.0 26.703794,37.8000355,0.0 26.7052317,37.8002729,0.0 26.7067122,37.8006375,0.0 26.7095018,37.8014089,0.0
</coordinates></LineString></MultiGeometry>'),4326));
```

Update After the inserts i create topology and other step from the
http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/topology.html for make a pgRouting for the insert data but when i run the `pgr_dijkstra` the query is

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra('
            SELECT id AS id,
                     source::integer,
                     target::integer,
                     length::double precision AS cost
                     FROM roads',
            30, 60, false, false);
```

Give me this error ERROR:  Target vertex was not found.
I dont find the reason

Comment: It isn't entirely clear from this what your problem is. With the insert, the routing?

Comment: it dont execute inserts and tells me that does not fit Multilinestring with linestring(from kml)

Answer (score 1):

For pgRouting it's not a good idea to have "real" multi-geometries. It's better to only use `LineString`.

Also your KML geometry contains a `Z` value, so you either use a 3D geometry or you use `ST_Force_2D` to ignore the `Z` values. Otherwise it will return an error like "Geometry has Z dimension but column does not".

I modified your SQL slightly, and this should be a working example:

```
CREATE TABLE roads(
    "id" serial,
    "name" text NOT NULL,
    "length" numeric CHECK("length" > 0),
    "the_geom" geometry("LineString",4326)
);
```

... to create the table with a 2D LineString geometry column. Then insert a record with:

```
INSERT INTO roads("name","length","the_geom") 
    VALUES(
        'Kwnn/nou Kanarh', 1000, 
        ST_Force_2D(
            ST_SetSRID(
                ST_GeomFromKML('<LineString><coordinates> 
                    26.683023,37.7939654,0.0 
                    26.6839457,37.7941011,0.0 
                    26.6857266,37.7944063,0.0 
                    26.687851,37.7948472,0.0 
                    26.69034,37.7955084,0.0 
                    26.6947603,37.7972888,0.0 
                    26.6975284,37.7980687,0.0 
                    26.6992879,37.7984926,0.0 
                    26.701498,37.7993573,0.0 
                    26.7026782,37.79989990000001,0.0 
                    26.703794,37.8000355,0.0 
                    26.7052317,37.8002729,0.0 
                    26.7067122,37.8006375,0.0 
                    26.7095018,37.8014089,0.0
                </coordinates></LineString>'
            ),4326)
        )
    );
```